# Finding $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x 3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do we prove that $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x \cdot 3^x}{(3^x-1)^2} \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{3\log{3}-2\log{2}}{2\log^2{3}}$$

I have tried some substitutions such as $3^x=t$, but it didn't work out. The denominator is already factored. I do not know what to do next. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating by parts ($u=x$, $dv=\frac{3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}dx$), $$\int x\frac{3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}dx=x\int\frac{3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}dx-\int\left[\frac{dx}{dx}\int\frac{3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}dx\right]dx$$

Now for $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}dx,$  set $3^x-1=u$

Finally $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{3^x-1},$ set $3^x-1=v$

Answer (score 3):

Another answers are nice but if you want to stick to Integration by parts, Here's how

$$I_1=\int_1^\infty\frac{x 3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}$$

$$I=\int\frac{x 3^x}{(3^x-1)^2}$$
substitute
$$3^x-1=t\iff3^x\ln 3=dt$$

$$I=\int\frac{x \cdot 3^x}{(3^x-1)^2} \mathrm{d}x= \frac{1}{\ln^23}\int \frac{\ln|t+1|}{t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$I(\ln^23)= \int \frac{\ln|t+1|}{t^2} \mathrm{d}t=-\frac{\ln|t+1|}{t}+\int \frac{1}{t(t+1)} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$I(\ln^23)=-\frac{\ln|t+1|}{t}-\ln|t|+\ln|t+1|$$

$$I=\frac{(3^x-1)\ln|1-3^x|-3^xx\ln(3)}{(\ln^23)(3^x-1)}$$

$$\rightarrow I_1=\frac{\ln27-\ln4}{2\ln^23}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{1}^{\infty}{x\ 3^{x} \over \pars{3^{x} - 1}^{2}}\,\dd x
     ={3\ln\pars{3} - 2\ln\pars{2} \over 2\ln^{2}\pars{3}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \expo{\mu x} - 1}}
> =\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-\mu x}\,\dd x \over 1 - \expo{-\mu x}}
> =\left.{\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-\mu x}} \over \mu}
> \right\vert_{x\ =\ 1}^{x\ \to\ \infty}
> =-\,{\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-\mu}} \over \mu}
> \end{align}

Derivate both members respect of $\ds{\mu}$:

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{1}^{\infty}%
> \bracks{-\,{x\expo{\mu x} \over \pars{\expo{\mu x} - 1}^{2}}}\,\dd x}
> =-\,{1 \over \mu\pars{\expo{\mu} - 1}} + {\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-\mu}} \over \mu^{2}}
> \end{align}

Multiply both members by $\ds{-1}$ and set $\ds{\mu = \ln\pars{3}}$:

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{1}^{\infty}%
> {x\ 3^{x} \over \pars{3^{x} - 1}^{2}}\,\dd x}
> ={1 \over \ln\pars{3}\pars{3 - 1}} - {\ln\pars{1 - 1/3} \over \ln^{2}\pars{3}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{3\ln\pars{3} - 2\ln\pars{2} \over 2\ln^{2}\pars{3}}}
> \\[5mm]&\approx {\tt 0.7911}
> \end{align}